# How to configure the RestClient client of RestSharp to be redirected to the .pdf file?

Tags: c#, rest, restsharp

When I am sending GET requests using chrome browser with the `Talend API Tester` I am getting HTTP Status Code `301 (Moved Permanently)` and am redirected to the .pdf document. This is expected and desired behavior.

Now, I am implementing this in `C# .NET Core 6` using the `RestSharp`. When I send the exact same request to the exact same endpoint I am receiving `200 OK` and the `JSON` object.

If I add  `client.FollowRedirects = false;`, then the status code of the response is `301`, however, I am getting a link to a `JSON` file instead of .pdf.

Is any way to configure the `RestClient client` of `RestSharp` so that be able to receive the link of the .pdf as it does with the `Talend API Tester`?

I spend the day on this... Any help or suggestions would be huge.

Comment: Looks like the problem not in the redirects, but in some headers/cookies/etc, and due to this the server return the json instead of pdf. Try to use Fiddler or other proxy/sniffer to log requests from browser and from C# and then carefully compare those request. Then fix your code in order to eliminate any differences between your and browser-issued requsts.

Comment: You can trace RestSharp requests like this https://restsharp.dev/v107/#delegating-handlers